# Python Infinite Loop on List

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop

I'm sure it's something very obvious that I am missing but can someone tell me why this code snippet continues in an endless loop?

```
bucket = [['Louis', 29], ['Nick', 2], ['Rochelle', 4]]

def find_index(bucket,keyword):
    index = 0
    for e in bucket:
        while e[0] <> keyword:
            index = index + 1
    return index


print find_index(bucket,'Nick')
```

Comment: The index in the `while` loop always remains `0`: `while e[0]...` should be `while e[index]...` Since you do not update the "check" (so to speak) the result of the condition will always remain the same.

Comment: The index is supposed to increment by one every time the keyword is not found in the element of the list currently being evaluated.

Comment: Do not use `<>`. I'm pretty sure it was deprecated in Python 2, and it hasn't ever existed on Python 3 AFAIK.

Comment: "The index is suppose to" yes, `index` does, but you **always try** `e[0] <> keyword` which is *always * `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ?
Two for-loops to prevent the loop running infinite.

```
bucket = [['Louis', 29], ['Nick', 2], ['Rochelle', 4]]

def find_index(bucket, keyword):
    for index, subArray in enumerate(bucket):
        for element in subArray:
            if element == keyword:
                return index

print find_index(bucket, 'Nick')
```

Comment: This one worked.  Thanks!  In my code I though e[0] would just continue to reference the zero element of each element of the main list.  Not just stay on zero.

Comment: Yes, take care with while loop. Always make sure that the condition(s) will be met or the loop terminates somehow (break).

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
bucket = [['Louis', 29], ['Nick', 2], ['Rochelle', 4]]

def find_index(bucket,keyword):
    index = 0
    for e in bucket:
        while e[index] <> keyword:
            index = index + 1
    return index


print find_index(bucket,'Nick')
```

You have used `e[0]` instead of `e[index]`.

Comment: Don't you mean `e[index]` instead of `e[0]`?

Comment: e[index] does not give me a good result either.  I get an IndexError: list index our of range error.  I think e[0] should work since I am asking to check the zero element of each sub list. Or at least that what I am trying to do.  I am expecting 1 from this code.

Comment: if the keyword is always in e[0]  why the `while` loop? `for e in bucket` already does the iteration, returning the lists